# netperf - get output of actual test?

Tags: networking

I installed `netperf` on both my PC and remote server. Now I try to run this test:

```
netperf -H remotehost.com -t TCP_STREAM
```

But nothing happens, no output. I can only stop it uzing ctl+z. So how do I get actual output and see some results? Isn't it supposed to run 10 seconds (on default) and then output something?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I guess it is not running when one server is your local PC. I tried on server to server test, it runs fine.